# Sql memory leak while executing "DBCC CHECKDB" command in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

We are using SQL server 2014 SP2 and We have heavily loaded database with around 6 GB of data and we created a custom tool for taking full/incremental backup which internally execute sql backup command but we see when ever DB backup starts , "DBCC CHECKDB" sql command execution itself takes around 5 to 6 minutes to execute and 'SQL server' memory shoots up from 300 MB to almost 6 GB out of 8 GB and never comes down even after backup is finished.

While searching further we found a Microsoft support link which also point out same SQL memory leak issue due to “DBCC CHECKDB” in SQL server 2014 version (https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3034615/fix-memory-leak-occurs-when-you-run-dbcc-checkdb-against-a-database-in ) and Microsoft was advising to install the latest SQL server 2014 hotfix patches to resolve this issue . So we also tried installing latest 2014 patches in performance server, but even after installing the latest patches, memory leak issue still not resolved yet.

System details :

Windows Server 2012 R2 :  Physical Machine

SQL server 2014 SP2

Windows Server memory : 8 GB

Any help on this is highly appreciated !!

Comment: Did you consider that SQL Server caches as much as it can? If you don't limit caching in SQL Server, it'll take the whole memory if it can. It will never release this memory, unless the server deals with memory pressure from other processes.

Comment: How much memory does your Windows Server have? What is the SQL Server memory configuration of your SQL Server instance? What version of Windows are you using? Is your Server a virtual server or a physical server? Please add as much details as possible to your question.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 : Physical Machine

SQL server 2014 SP2


Windows Server memory : 8 GB

SQL Server memory configuration : 2147483644 MB Max

Comment: Memory use <> memory leak. I expect SQL Server will use the buffer pool pages cached by `DBCC CHECKDB` for other requests and reuse cache entries when new pages need to be read from storage.

Answer (score 1):

#### What Does DBCC CHECKDB do?

It checks the consistency of the database.

#### How Does DBCC Do That?

Well it's going to have to read (all) the data to verify it is correct.

#### How does DBCC CHECKDB read the data?

It will read the data like any other process that requires data. First it will have a look at the memory assigned to the SQL Server instance and see if the data is stored in RAM. If it doesn't find the data in the memory assigned to the SQL Server instance, then it will fetch the data from disk and store that in the SQL Server memory assigned to the instance for future retrieval. If the data pages already allocated in memory aren't stale, then SQL Server's database engine will try to allocate more memory to the SQL Server instance, up until the `max server memory (MB)' in the advanced options.

#### Will SQL Server Release Memory?

No. Read the article [A Sysadmin’s Guide to Microsoft SQL Server Memory](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/) for more details.

#### Can I Tell SQL Server to Release Memory?

Yes. You can release (some of) the memory held by the SQL Server instance, by issuing/performing one of the following commands/tasks:

1. `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`
2. `DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB`
3. `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE`
4. `DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE`
5. `DBCC FLUSHAUTHCACHE`
6. `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`
7. Changing the **Minimum server memory (in MB)** or **Maximum server memory (in MB)** memory setting for your SQL Server instance.
8. Restarting the instance.

> **DISCLAIMER:**
> It is not recommended to manually clean up memory cache in SQL Server as this can have an adverse impact on the SQL Server instances performance.
> It is not recommended to restart the SQL Server instance just because of memory pressure. This is only a last resort when all else fails.

#### What Can I Do to Limit the Memory SQL Server Uses?

You can limit the amount of memory used by setting the **Minimum server memory (in MB)** and **Maximum server memory (in MB)** setting for your SQL Server instance.

### Answering Your Question

Your SQL Server instances is doing exactly what it was designed to do: It is consuming as much memory as possible to achieve peak performance when reading data from the database(s) via memory. **There is no memory leak**

### Further Reading/Reference Material

- [A Sysadmin’s Guide to Microsoft SQL Server Memory](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/) (BrentOzar.com)
- [How much memory does my SQL Server actually need?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/) (SQLSkills.com)
- [Wow… An online calculator to misconfigure your SQL Server memory!](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/wow-an-online-calculator-to-misconfigure-your-sql-server-memory/) (SQLSkills.com)
- [Server Memory Server Configuration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft Docs)